# Not able to open vb6 output file

Tags: vb6

I am new to Visual basic 6 and I use it to run a code (not written by me) for my data analysis. One of the output file is tmaze1.1.rmap 
I am not able to open this file. what I know is, it has values in a  64 by 48 array.
I tried opening it through notepad, wordpad etc but it only shows symbols.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Some of us only get 50 close votes per day.  Please help us conserve them by reading [ask] and taking the [tour]

Comment: https://www.filetypeadvisor.com/extension/rmap?

Comment: what is the content of the file, what does the data represent? do you know which program has created the file?

Comment: I figured out it was a binary file. I was able to read the file in Matlab using fopen and fread command
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with a Hex editor. Google "free hex editor" to download one if you don't already have one installed. The Hex editor will allow you to read the values inside the file.

Comment: Yes I tried that too but it did not work as Hex editor decodes the symbols that appear when opened as text file. It does not show any value, just symbols with corresponding hexadecimal values.

Comment: The hexadecimal values are the values stored in the file. I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I figured out it was a binary file. I was able to read the file in Matlab using fopen and fread command.
Thanks.